# How to grab a value from a dictionary which contains multiple keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
 mydict = {'950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073': 'value1', '400856,400857,400858,400859,400860,400861': 'value2', '920100': 'value3', '950107,950109,950108': 'value4'}
```

My question is, how do I obtain value `value1` by using only one of the keys e.g `950001`?

In other words, I want to do something like:

```
mydict['950001']
```

and get printed:

```
value1
```

I know I may reverse the keys and values, but in this case it won't work for the script I am working on.

Comment: Technically speaking, 950001 is not a key, '950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073' is. You'd want to recreate the dictionary with each comma separated int as a key.

Comment: your dictionary does not have multiple keys. you would have to search the keys to find one that matches doing a linear search

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary in Python consist of key-value-pairs. So in your example, *one* key would be `'950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073'`. In my explanations below, I will call `950001`, `959070` and so on just "numbers".

---

**Method 1:** You could write a loop over all keys of your `dict` and split each key into a list at every comma `,` with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Your list then contains your numbers and you can check if your requested number `n` is in there:

```
mydict = {'950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073': 'value1', '400856,400857,400858,400859,400860,400861': 'value2', '920100': 'value3', '950107,950109,950108': 'value4'}

n = '950001'
for key in mydict:
    if n in key.split(','):
        print(mydict[key])
```

Which prints:

```
value1
```

---

**Method 2:** Alternatively, you could convert your dictionary `mydict` into a new dictionary `new_dict` so every number gets its own key:

```
mydict = {'950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073': 'value1', '400856,400857,400858,400859,400860,400861': 'value2', '920100': 'value3', '950107,950109,950108': 'value4'}

new_dict = {}
for key in mydict:
    for new_key in key.split(','):
        new_dict[new_key] = mydict[key]

print(new_dict)
```

Which prints:

```
{'950001': 'value1', '959070': 'value1', '959071': 'value1', '959072': 'value1', '950908': 'value1', '959073': 'value1', '400856': 'value2', '400857': 'value2', '400858': 'value2', '400859': 'value2', '400860': 'value2', '400861': 'value2', '920100': 'value3', '950107': 'value4', '950109': 'value4', '950108': 'value4'}
```

Then you can access your value just like you said with `new_dict['950001']`.

---

The code above is written with emphasis on clarity. Depending on your use case, you could write a function and/or use a **`dict` [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** to make your code look nicer if you're comfortable with that:

```
mydict = {'950001,959070,959071,959072,950908,959073': 'value1', '400856,400857,400858,400859,400860,400861': 'value2', '920100': 'value3', '950107,950109,950108': 'value4'}
new_dict = {nk: v for k, v in mydict.items() for nk in k.split(',')}
print(new_dict['950001'])
```

Comment: no need to split

Comment: If the same number appears in several keys beware that the alternative solution will only show one of the values

Comment: If you do not split them, you are not using your dictionary as a dictionary, you are using it as a list.

Answer (score -2):

```
def get_value(n):
    newdict = {
        "value1": ["950001", "959070", "959071", "959072", "950908", "959073"],
        "value2": ["400856", "400857", "400858", "400859", "400860", "400861"],
        "value3": ["920100"],
        "value4": ["950107", "950109", "950108"]
    }
    # Loop through dictionary to find a match and its value
    for value, nums in newdict.items():
        if n in nums:
            return(value)
```

Comment: Solutions should generalize to any keys and values. Usually the example is just to illustrate the problem

Comment: To clarify what @Untitled123 said, the values are not necessarily unique.